# error: incompatible types for a function that returns float in C

Tags: c, function, floating-point, return-type

Its an extremely simple code but I can't figure out the problem..

```
float fare;
fare = calculate_fare(stops);

float calculate_fare(int stops)
{
    int stops_left = stops;
    float fare = 10.0;
    if (stops != 17)
    {
        stops_left = stops - 5;
        while (stops_left>0)
        {
            fare += 5.0;
            stops_left -= 5;
        }
    }
    if (stops == 17)
    {
        fare = 20.0;
    }

    return fare;
}
```

I get the error: conflicting types for 'calculate_fare'
previous implicit decleration for 'calculate_fare' was here

I've already tried returning a double instead of float but it doesnt work too. Also, tried writing floats as 10.0f , even that doesnt work. Also tried typecasting the float to be returned.
This program does have a working function that returns an int.
Ran the code on codeblocks.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code so that it's readable.

Comment: Please put function definition before usage

Comment: You mention one error in the title and a second one in your post

Comment: If you haven't got another warning (for the implicit declaration itself), you should switch to a C99 (or C11) compiler (for Gcc and Clang with `-std=c99 -pedantic`, for example), or raise your warning options (if you have a reason to compile with a C89 compiler).

Comment: You write you get `conflicting types for 'calculate_fare' previous implicit decleration for 'calculate_fare' was here`. The compiler tells you where `here` is, so let us know where `here` is if you want an aswer,

Answer (score 3):

If C compiler does not know the function signature, it deduces input parameters based on arguments supplied, and deduces return type to be `int`.

Either declare the function before you use it for the first time:

```
float calculate_fare(int stops);
```

or put entire definition at the top of your translation unit.

That is, the error:

```
[...] previous implicit declaration for 'calculate_fare' was here [...]
//             ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

states that the compiler had no previous declaration for the function, and had to *generate* one on its own.

Answer (score 3):

You are compiling against an older compiler standard (before C99), which allows implicit declarations. So when you write:

```
fare = calculate_fare(stops);
```

the compiler, which has noy yet encountered a declaration for `calculate_fare`, implicitly declares it with a return type of `int`. And with a single parameter with whatever type `stops` has, subject to default promotions.

Later you supply the definition of the function with a different return type. And that's what the compiler complains about. You should declare the function before calling it:

```
float calculate_fare(int stops);
```

Or move the function definition to be before the first call to it.